# Dojo EnhancedGrid Row not editable after save

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I want to edit some values inside an enhancedgrid. For the first time it works well. The item is send to server via JSONRest and the values are stored on Server. If i want to do more edits in the same row, the row is freezed in. Other rows are editable.
I use AMD-Style-Syntax

The Reststore comes here:

```
_listenStore: new Cache(new JsonRest({
        target: "Liste/",
        idProperty: "id",
        editable: true
    }),new Memory()),
```

The Grid is coming up during startup() of the Widget

```
this._wuListenGrid=new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
                selectionMode: "single",
                store: new ObjectStore({objectStore: this._listenStore}),
                structure: this._strukturListen,
                nestedSorting: true,
                editable: true,
                singleClickEdit: true,
                keepSelection: false,
                alwaysEditing: true
            });
domConstruct.place(this._wuListenGrid.domNode,this.cpListen.domNode, "last");
this._wuListenGrid.startup();
```

The structure is defined outside, but works as expected. The editable fields are defined with 'editable': true

I'll do the save with

```
this._wuListenGrid.store.save();
```

If save() is called, the RestStore submit the changed items ondemand. So I think the store-part should be oK.

Comment: are you getting any error during multiple edits? also, did you try this with multiple browsers?

Comment: there are no errors. I tried in IE, Chrome and Firefox. Same problem in every of theme.